# Sorting one column of data into multiple columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting, spreadsheet

If I have a list of data in a spreadsheet like this:

```
John
123-456-7890
john@email.com
Sally
987-654-3210
sally@email.com
.
.
.
```

What would be the quickest and cleanest way to sort the data into rows and columns like

```
John  |  123-456-7890  |  john@email.com
Sally |  987-654-3210  |  sally@email.com
.
.
.
```

I have found the forumula `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,(ROW()-1)*#,0)` that will help me get data from every # (eg 5th) row but I was wondering if there was a cleaner way

Comment: That general type of solution is a pretty standard way of doing this.  Use a formula in the three columns that does the math to identify which row's cell goes in that position.

Answer (score 2):

**This method will help you to Copy Data from Rows into Columns:**

[image]

- Enter this Formula in Cell `C1` then fill Right & Down.

  ```
  =OFFSET($A$1,COLUMNS($A:A)-1+(ROWS($1:1)-1)*3,0)
  ```

**If your data starts from other then Row 1, then you may use this Formula:**

- Formula in Cell `D109`, fill it Right then Down.

  ```
  =OFFSET($A$109,COLUMNS($A:A)-1+(ROWS($109:109)-1)*3,0)
  ```

[image]

**N.B.**

- In used Data set every new name occurs after 3 Rows therefore `(ROWS($1:1)-1)*3`, mutiplied by `3`, which is editable, as the Row interval changes.
- Adjust Cell references in the Formula as needed.